# Does this work to prove that the cantor set lacks isolated points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cantor-set

I came up with this idea to show that the Cantor set lacks isolated points (i.e. every point is a limit point) but I'm not sure if it works.

Let $C$ be the Cantor middle third set. My goal is to show that for any $x \in C$ and  $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $y \in C$ such that $|x - y| < \varepsilon$.

We can write

$$C = \left\{ \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_i}{3^i} : a_i \in \{0, 2\}} \right\}.$$

So, let $x \in C$ such that $x = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{a_i/2^i}$. For $\varepsilon > 0$, we find $k$ such that $2/2^k < \varepsilon$ and we take $y \in C$ where $y = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{b_i/2^i}$ such that

$$b_i = \begin{cases}
a_i & i \neq k \\
2 - a_i & i = k
\end{cases}.$$

So, we know $y \in C$ and $|x - y| = 2/2^k < \varepsilon$.

Does this work?

Comment: A perfect set is one that's closed and lacks of isolated points. You need to prove closedness.

Comment: Instead of 2s in the denominators, you need 3s. The set you wrote down is the interval $[0,2]$.

Comment: @LucaT.Castrillón gotcha, thanks! I got the definition wrong. I changed it to a question about isolated points.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo good catch, thank you! Fixed.